# How to convert a sequential object into numpy array in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray, sequential

Here I have to convert the generated object in to numpy array but it is in sequential format. How can I do that in Tensorflow 2?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frxh7.png)

Comment: It is not in a sequential format. It is object of a class called Sequential which is how you can represent the whole model in keras. You can't just take an arbitrary data structure and turn it into an array, it contains a lot of information that cannot be reasonably encoded in an array.

Comment: Could you please show the code?